# What is the normal form of this lambda calculus and are there any free variables?

Tags: lambda-calculus

I am trying to learn lambda calculus, but I am having a hard time doing it. So if anyone would explain a little bit, I would greatly appreciate it!

```
(λj.λx.f(j x)) (λy.f y)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is one free variable, `f`. `j`, `x`, and `y` are all bound by an abstraction.

There are two ways you can reach normal form. Either perform two beta reductions

```
(λj.λx.f(j x)) (λy.f y) == (λx.f((λy.f y) x))  apply (λj.λx.f(j x)) to (λy.f y) 
                        == (λx.f(f x))         apply (λy.f y) to x
```

or perform an eta reduction followed by a beta reduction.

```
(λj.λx.f(j x)) (λy.f y) == (λj.λx.f(j x)) f   replace (λy.f y) with f 
                        == (λx.f(f x))        apply (λj.λx.f(j x)) to f
```

Comment: Thank you very much, wasn't sure for this step `(λj.λx.f(j x)) to (λy.f y) `.

Comment: Additionally, this happens to be a strongly normalizing term, as both of the possible sequences of rewriting produce the normal form.